# How to get Dart Flutter floatActionButton bottom right?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a screen like this:

[image]

I'm trying to place the `floatActionButton` at the bottom right, but I couldn't.I'm putting the `floatActionButton`, but I couldn't put it in the bottom right.

How can I put it in the bottom right?

Codes:

```
Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 40),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 15,),
                  Text("Profile", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 27),),
                  Divider(thickness: 1, color: Colors.black,),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text("Solved Tests:",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19)),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 200,
                    child: Expanded(
                      child: FutureBuilder(
                      future: listUpload(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        late List<String?> items;
                        if (!snapshot.hasData){
                          return Text("Not found");
                        }
                        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        items = [];
                        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                          snapshot.hasData) {
                        items = snapshot.data as List<String?>;
                        } else {
                          items = [];
                        }
                        return Scrollbar(
                          isAlwaysShown: true,
                          controller: _scrollContreller,
                          scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.right,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            controller: _scrollContreller,
                            itemCount: items.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, left: 10, right: 10),
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    
                                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  ),
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    title: Text(
                                      items[index].toString(),
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                    })),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 15,),
                  Center(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                        child: Container(
                          width: 250,
                          height: 40,
                          child: GFButton(
                            text: "Temizle", textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.red),
                            color: Colors.red,
                            type: GFButtonType.outline2x,
                            onPressed: () {
                              AlertDialog eminlik = AlertDialog(
                                title: Text("Onay"),
                                content: Text("Çözdüğünüz testlerin kayıtları silinecektir. Emin misiniz?"),
                                actions: [
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: Text("Evet"),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                      setState(() {
                                        eminlikSil();
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: Text("Hayır"),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },
                                  )
                                ],
                              );
                              showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => eminlik);
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      
                      ],
                    ),
                      
                  ),
                  // !!!!!!!!!!! <<<<<<<<<
                  // !!!!!!!!!!! <<<<<<<<<
                  FloatingActionButton(
                  child: Text("FAB"),  
                  onPressed: () {}),
                  
                ],
              ),
              
            ),
            
          ),
```

In the code I provided, I commented out where I put the `floatActionButton`.I put the codes of the screen in the picture directly. floatActionButton codes are below.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want the achieve the default material design behaviour, in that case use a `Scaffold` and set the `floatingActionButton` value

```
return Scaffold(
  body: , // paste your page content here
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Text("FAB"),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
);
```

Your floating action button will placed at the bottom because it's the default behaviour, if you want to change that play with the value of `floatingActionButtonLocation`

if you don't want to relay on `Scaffold` use a `Stack` widget instead

```
return Stack(
  children: [
    // paste your page content here
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text("FAB"),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put the `floatingActionButton` as a named parameter of `Scaffold`.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Floating Action Button'),
      ),
      body: const Center(child: Text('Press the button below!')),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Add your onPressed code here!
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Reference: [official flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to add a `FloatingActionButton` is to add it directly to your `Scaffold`.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Another solution would be to encapsulate your view in a `Stack` and to add your `FloatingActionButton` in an `Align`.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: [
        Container(),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        )
      ],)
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set Alignment for use [`Container`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) or [`Align`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) Widget .

Using Container:

```
 Container(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
    child: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Icon(
        Icons.add,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Using Align:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
  child: Container(
    child: FloatingActionButton(
      hoverColor: Colors.black,
      elevation: 10,
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Icon(
        Icons.add,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Using Scaffold:

```
Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
    );
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're using Scaffold, it has `floatingActionButton` parameter. Where you should put your float, and if it doesn't place it to position you want you can correct it with `floatingActionButtonLocation` parameter.
Example:

```
Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
)
```

Otherwise, you can wrap `FloatActionButton` with `Align` widget. And give it alignment as you want.